# Function $f(x)$ such that $f(x-i)+f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Help me find a function $f(x)$ such that

$$f(x-i)+f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: Is the edit correct? Did you try anything? If you show where you're stuck, it's easier to help.

Comment: I think the answer does not exist. ($x = -i, 0, i$)

Comment: Are there any further conditions on the function? If not, and you ignore the obvious issue at $x=0$, then you can take any function on $\mathbb R \times [0,1) \subset \mathbb C$ and extend it uniquely to a solution using the functional equation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution, in terms of a "polygamma" function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function

Let $f(x) = \psi^{(1)}(ix)$ then we have $f(x-i)-f(x) = 1/x^2$ if my calculations are correct.  This is based on the formula for the diagmma
$$
\psi(x+1)-\psi(x) = \frac{1}{x},
$$
then differentiate to get $1/x^2$ and use $ix$ since your increment is $-i$.

Comment: Great job thanks